# Generating random keys in C#

Tags: c#, random

I am making a vigenere encryption program in c# and i want to generate a random key, but trying to get my head around this working first.

So in my V class i have a method:

```
class V
{
    public static string GenerateKey(int length)
    {
        StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] rnd = new byte[1];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < key.Length)
        {
            rng.GetBytes(rnd);
            rnd[0] %= 64;
            if (rnd[0] < 62)
            {
                ++i;
                key.Append((byte)((rnd[0] <= 9 ? '0' : rnd[0] <= 35 ? 'A' - 10 : 'a' - 36) + rnd[0]));
            }
        }
        return key.ToString();
    }
```

and in my MainClass class i have the Main method which contains:

```
Console.WriteLine(V.GenerateKey(10));
```

But it does not produce anything upon compilation just a blank console, I am still a new to C# so please don't be offended by any mistakes.

Comment: do you mean `i` not `n` in the while loop?

Comment: How long do you want the key to be? Have you specified this? at the moment the loop goes up to `key.length` which is 0 at the beginning.

Comment: sorry yes n in the while loop is supposed to be i @SanjayManohar

Comment: Learn to debug. Set breakpoints, step through your code and inspect the relevant variables.

Comment: @JamesThorpe in the Main class i have:

`Console.WriteLine(V.GenerateKey(10));` and the (10) is setting the int length to 10

Comment: Why not just create a byte array of the required length and have .GetBytes do all the work at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 while (i < length)
```

you need to go up to the desired length! (not the current length)